# Scala Iterable[(String, Long)] to SortedMap[String,Long] or TreeMap[String, Long] sorted in decreasing order of value

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections

```
object Test extends App {
 val i: Iterable[(String, Long)] = List(("a", 1), ("b", 2))
  val sortedMap: SortedMap[String, Long] = i.toList.sortBy(_._2)
}
```

I don't want to convert Iterable to List/Array etc since it's coming form a jdbc query.

Comment: Also.. why do you not want to convert it to a list? If you want it to be a map..simply to .toMap ? I am genuinely confused too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. `SortedMap` sorts by keys, not values. 
If you want it sorted by value, you gotta use `ListMap`, and can't avoid converting to `List`:

```
 ListMap(i.toList.sortBy(-_._2):_*)
```

There isn't really too much wrong with converting to list, since you are loading the whole thing in memory anyway. This is faster too, than building a tree one element at a time.